# Remove blanks from end of line

Tags: c, string, console-application

I am trying print line without blank space at begin and end.
I can't figured out why removing from end doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 1000

#define LINE_BEGIN 0
#define LINE_MIDDLE 1
#define INBLANK 2


void deleteBlankFromEnd(char line[], int offset);
void deleteLine(char line[], int offset);

main()
{
    int c, i, status ;
    i = status = 0;
    char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF) { 
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\t') {
            if (status == LINE_MIDDLE || status == INBLANK) {
                line[i++] = c;
                if (status == LINE_MIDDLE)
                    status = INBLANK;
            }
        } else if (c == '\n') {
            if (status > 0) {
                if (status == INBLANK) {
                    printf("Line length = %d ", i);
                    deleteBlankFromEnd(line, i); 
                }
                printf("%s", line);
                printf("End\n");

                deleteLine(line, i);
            }
            i = 0;
            status = LINE_BEGIN;
        } else {
            line[i++] = c;
            status = LINE_MIDDLE;
        }
    }
}

void deleteBlankFromEnd(char line[], int offset) {
    while (line[offset] == ' ' || line[offset] == '\t') {
        line[offset--] = 0;
    }
    printf("Line length = %d ", offset);
}

void deleteLine(char line[], int offset) {
    while (offset >= 0) {
        line[offset--] = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an off-by-one indexing error to me. Your deleteBlankFromEnd will do nothing if the character at the initial offset is not a blank space or a tab; try finding out what it is? You might need to start with --i

Answer (score 1):

You pass to `deleteBlankFromEnd` function wrong offset that is in your case equal to length of input. By this your trying to access content that is actually out of bounds here:

```
while (line[offset] == ' ' || line[offset] == '\t')
```

you better to call deleteBlankFromEnd like below:

```
deleteBlankFromEnd(line, i-1);
```

where second arg will point to the last character in string.